# How to gracefully resize width and height of boostrap 2.3 modal and still remain in the center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-2

How can I gracefully resize the width and height of boostrap 2.3 and still remain in the center without any flicker of bootstrap modal ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some code or expect little to none answers, see http://stackoverflow.com/help for help on how to make a question

Comment: flicker, what flicker? must be some code doing that but we don't have crystal balls to see that code